# Matlab vectorization of cartesian product

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Let's say I have two arrays X and Y and I need a matrix M(i, j) = some_func(X(i), Y(j)). How can I get that without using loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer is to use bsxfun, IF it is an option. According to the help for bsxfun, it will work on any general dyadic function, as long as:

```
  FUNC can also be a handle to any binary element-wise function not listed
    above. A binary element-wise function in the form of C = FUNC(A,B)
    accepts arrays A and B of arbitrary but equal size and returns output
    of the same size. Each element in the output array C is the result
    of an operation on the corresponding elements of A and B only. FUNC must
    also support scalar expansion, such that if A or B is a scalar, C is the
    result of applying the scalar to every element in the other input array.
```

If your function accepts only scalar input, then loops are the simple alternative.

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to answer your vague question, and it ultimately depends on your function. What you can do is use `meshgrid` and then perform your operation, typically with use of the dot operator

e.g.

```
x = 1:5;
y = 1:3;

[X,Y] = meshgrid (x,y)

M = X.^Y;
```